# Are the outputs of generalized linear models no longer linear in the parameters?

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model

I'm reading *Mathematics for Machine learning*, and I came across the following passage regarding Generalized Linear Models: "Note that although we are talking about “generalized linear models”, the outputs y are no longer linear in the parameters θ"

I'm a little confused by this since for logistic regression (for example), the outputs do seem to be linear in the parameters. What am I missing?

Comment: The probability output of a logistic regression is not linear in the parameters.

Comment: @Dave Yes: but the log odds output *is* linear.  By the same token, one could claim the outputs of ordinary least squares regression are "not linear" if one prefers reporting the exponential of a number rather than the number itself, even though that doesn't change the model or its results: it's just a matter how one prefers to express numerical values.  In this sense I think claims about "nonlinear" output of a GLM are somewhere between useless and misleading.